# Published Facebook Feed can Only be Seen by Self

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, libgdx, android-simple-facebook

I'm using [sromku](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) to share score from my LibGDX game.

The feed was successfully published, but no one can see it but myself (even when my profile is seen by others).

Code:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements FacebookConn {
    SimpleFacebook mSimpleFacebook;
    OnPublishListener onPublishListener = new OnPublishListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String postId) {
            Log.i("OnComplete", "Published successfully. The new post id = " + postId);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Permission[] permissions = new Permission[] {
            Permission.USER_PHOTOS,
            Permission.EMAIL,
            Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION,
        };

        SimpleFacebookConfiguration configuration = 
            new SimpleFacebookConfiguration.Builder()
            .setAppId("410074072507300")
            .setNamespace("sromkuapp")
            .setPermissions(permissions)
            .build();

        SimpleFacebook.setConfiguration(configuration);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useImmersiveMode = true;
        initialize(new Jump4Love(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScore(int score) {
        Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
        .setMessage("message")
        .setName("name")
        .setCaption("caption")
        .setDescription("description")
        .setPicture("picture")
        .setLink("link")
        .build();
        // Note: the values above aren't the actual values I'm using
        // I only simplified them so my code becomes easier to read

        mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, true, onPublishListener);
    } 
}
```

I found a similar case in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126136/facebook-sdk-feed-own-timeline-only-not-on-friends-news-feed).
The OP said the following:

> Only without using "link" and "picture" it does appear on my friend's
>   News Feed

I tried removing the link and picture but the result was still the same, so my case is kinda different.
That post still has no acceptable answer btw.

**======================================================================**

It's useless to promote my game in Facebook if no one can see it.
I have seen posts from friends promoting other games, so I know it is possible.

Anyone has any idea why I'm having this problem?

Comment: Do you have given access to view by public? If that is only Me then it will be only seen by self.

Comment: Yes, I used a publish dialog so I could choose to show public, friends, or only me. Whatever I choose, the post still ends up in my wall only, cant be seen by others.

Comment: You need to set your app “live”. Go to Status&Review tab in app dashboard, on top you find _“Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”_ … that one you need to set to _Yes_.

Comment: @Jay Kazama OK. Try to do same thing with another account. If this is working fine with another account then you might have given security to your feed from the facebook.com. Just go there and check your security that whether you have correct selected or not. Let me know if still you are facing issue.

Comment: @CBroe: Wow it works! Thanks, I've been looking through everywhere with no answer, finally! Please answer my question below, so I can accept it.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer: It has been resolved, thanks for ur concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your app “live”.

Go to *Status & Review* tab in app dashboard, on top you find

> “Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”

… that one you need to set to **Yes**.

Before setting this to Yes, your app is considered to be in “development mode”, and therefor posts made via it are not shown to users that do not have a role in your app (admin/developer/tester).